# How to add a touch equivalent to .mouseLeave

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help to add a touch function equivalent to `.mouseLeave` in the script below so the hover effect will leave.

```
<figure class="snip1554">
  <img src=https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Jgc1bCFRMKJjy0Fhq6x.xpXao/FOCALLURE-18-Colors-Glitter-Eye-Shadow-Cosmetic-Makeup-Diamond-Lips-Loose-Makeup-Eyes-Pigment-Powder.jpg />
  <figcaption>
    <h3>Let them lose themselves in your eyes</h3>
  </figcaption>
  <a href="#"></a>
</figure>

<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:700;);
.snip1554 {
  background-color: #045e78;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-width: 315px;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.snip1554 * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.45s ease;
  transition: all 0.45s ease;
}

.snip1554:after {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  left: -100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px white;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

.snip1554 img {
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.snip1554 figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
}

.snip1554 h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  margin: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.snip1554 h3 span {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.snip1554 a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.snip1554:hover > img,
.snip1554.hover > img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.snip1554:hover:after,
.snip1554.hover:after {
  left: 200%;
}

.snip1554:hover figcaption,
.snip1554.hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>

<script>
$(".hover").mouseleave(
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
;
  }
);

</script>
```

The code I am talking about is in the script right above this paragraph. I need something for touch devices so that the hover effect is removed and does not just stay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **touchend()** (its similarly like mouseLeave)...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend

You can add same hover class for this one as well...
But you need to get the **useragent** first...

```js
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(Android|iPod|iPhone|iPad|IEMobile|BlackBerry|Opera Mini)/)){
  $('body').on('touchend','your element', function(){
    // something to trigger transition 
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey could you help me out with what code you would think I can put by an example using my .hover class? and where would I put it?

Comment: I cannot figure it out, wish you could just do it so I know what your talking about, lol.